# Resize Canvas with HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a problem that is:
In my web page I have two canvas that have the same width and height, and I have an icon that allows to resize my widget. So when I change the size of the widget, the first canvas is resized but not the second (it's fixed). Is it related to CSS problem? I didn't neither find how is done the resize of the first canvas.

Here is the CSS of the second canvas that doesnt change:

```
.enosho-light-gondola-highlight {
     position : absolute;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Please make a working fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If the button changes the CSS, then the css classname is probably not the same in both canvasses. Either change the script behind your button to change both classes or change the class to one single class.